# insert data to denormal table from normal table

Tags: sql

In my database i have some tables denormalized and a program that sends normal data to a procedure. some example of my tables like this:

Denormal table:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Id |Description| date | UserId1 | Percent1 | Desc1 | ... | UserId10 | Percent10 | Desc10|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | row 1     | 2014 |    10   |    10%   |       | ... |    1     |    30%    |       |
| 1 | row 2     | 2012 |     5   |     4%   |       | ... |    7     |    47%    |       |
| 2 | row 3     | 2015 |    20   |    30%   |       | ... |   25     |    33%    |       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and normal table from my program like:

```
---------------------------
| UserId | Percent | Desc | 
---------------------------
| 70     | 20      |      |
| 30     | 7       |      |
---------------------------
```

**NOTE:**

- Normal table should have max 10 rows
- Each row of normal table map to 3 columns (UserID#, Percent#, Desc#)

Now I should:

- Insert data from the program (normal) table to the denormal table
- Select from the denormal and pass result as normal to the program

How can I do this?

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that ?

Comment: this is incredibly messy. you can have UserId as a column in your db table, and another table for batches. you should keep all data normalized. It will prevent many headaches.

Comment: @Bartdude: to speed up the queries, for instance.

Comment: @Quassnoi > I'm no DB expert, but I don't see how denormalizing data then normalize it back again would speed up anything... But as I said I'm no DB expert, so maybe that's normal I don't get this.

Comment: @Bartdude: any index is in fact denormalized data. The only difference is that the database engine keeps indexes in sync with the tables automatically, but in complex cases like this you should do it manually.

Comment: Thx for explanation... I will keep that in mind as it doesn't seem natural at all to me.

Comment: Thanks for your replies but this tables design by my head and i cant change it.
@Bartdude How to do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve my problem by create command string and execute it.

```
DECLARE @ColNames nvarchar(max) = '[Description], [Date]'
DECLARE @Values nvarchar(max) = CAST(@Description AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ', ' +
    'CAST(''' + CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''' AS DATETIME), '


DECLARE @UserId BIGINT
DECLARE @Percent FLOAT
DECLARE @Desc nvarchar(300)
DECLARE @i INT = 1

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT [UserId], [Percent], [Desc] FROM Table2
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @UserId, @Percent, @Desc

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @i <= 10
BEGIN
    SET @ColNames +=  ', UserId' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(3)) +
                    ', Percent' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(3)) +
                    ', Desc' + CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR(3))

    SET @Values += CAST(@UserId  AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ', ' +
                CAST(@Percent  AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ', ' +
                'N''' + @Desc + ''', '

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @UserId, @Percent, @Desc
    SET @i += 1
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur

SET @Values = SUBSTRING(@Values, 1, LEN(@Values) - 1)

DECLARE @Command nvarchar(max) =
    'INSERT INTO Table1' +
    ' ( ' + @ColNames + ')' +
    ' VALUES ( ' + @Values + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql @Command
```

this work great and update procedure use this concept but I don't know about performance,  disadvantage of use this concept.